# Angular 2 Create nested objects

Tags: typescript, angular

I have 2 Components a ExpressionBuilderComponent:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'expression-builder',
    directives: [ExpressionComponent],
    template: `
        <div class="container">
           <expression *ngFor="#expression of expressions" [prototypes]="prototypes" [expression]="expression" [expressions]="expressions"></expression>
           <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addExpression()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
    `
})
```

And the ExpressionComponent:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'expression',
    directives: [ExpressionComponent],
    template: `
    <div class="row">

    <!-- First Select -->
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPrototypeSelector" (ngModelChange)="onPrototypeChange()">
                <option *ngFor="#p of prototypes" [value]="p.selector">
                    {{ p.selectorName }}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>

    <!-- Second Select -->
        <div [ngClass]="{'col-xs-3': prototype?.valueType !== 'Set', 'col-xs-2': prototype?.valueType === 'Set'}" *ngIf="prototype">
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="expression.constraint">
                <option *ngFor="#constraint of prototype.constraints" [value]="constraint">
                    {{ constraint }}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>

    <!-- Third Select -->
        <div [ngClass]="{'col-xs-3': prototype?.valueType !== 'Set', 'col-xs-2': prototype?.valueType === 'Set'}">
            <input *ngIf="expression && prototype?.valueType === 'Integer'" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="expression.value" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <a class="btn btn-danger pull-right" (click)="deleteExpression()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Expression Set selector -->
        <div *ngIf="prototype?.valueType === 'Set'">
           <expression [prototypes]="prototypes" [expression]="expression"></expression>
               <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addExpression()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
            </div>
       </div>
   })

export class ExpressionComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() expression:Expression;
   @Input() expressions:any[];
   @Input() prototype:ExpressionPrototype;
   @Input() prototypes:ExpressionPrototype[];
    ngOnInit() {

        if(this.expression.selector === 'conditionSet'){
            //this.prototypes = this.prototype.children;
            console.log(this.prototypes);
        }
    }

 addExpression() {
        this.expressions.push(new Expression());
        console.log(this.expressions);
    }
```

And These are the Objects:

```
export class Expression {
    selector: string;
    constraint: string;
    value: string;
    children: Expression[];
}

export class ExpressionPrototype {
    selector: string;
    selectorName: string;
    constraints: any[] = [];
    valueType: string;
}
```

How do I move all the prototypes to the expression.children, so that it becomes nested content now it will override each other when I select something because they have the same variable to bind data. And the same for the addExpression it must be in the nested content. I will show you in screenshot what I mean maybe its bit vague:[image]

I'll hope you have enough information :)

Here is a [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/2soqqn?p=preview)

Comment: What about a Plunker? I can't see from this code how the classes and components are connected.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer could you please help me: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZqNXjd?p=preview

Comment: You didn't provider the `ExpressionService` anywhere. I added it in https://plnkr.co/edit/xZJZPp?p=preview. No you get `Maximum call stack size exceeded` because each expression creates another expression within itself and so on, and so on. For recursion you need an exit marker. I added `*ngIf="expression"`. No idea what the exact intent is. There is still an error because the `ExpressionService` doesn't have a `getValue()` method.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thank you i did provide this in my main.ts -.-"

Comment: Ok, but not in the Plunker you linked to above.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I think you now get a clear view how it is constructed?

Comment: "Clear view" seems exaggerated ;-) So how do we proceed. Can you extend the Plunker to demonstrate the issue you run into?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109412/discussion-between-beginnerprogrammer-and-gunter-zochbauer).